# Why ListView Item of custom CursorAdapter does not respond with Image Button?

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

I have a ListView and a basic custom cursor adapter. When I add an imagebutton the List View Item does not respond to item click or long item click

how I am going to fix this? Do I need to set to clickable something?

Comment: You can show your adapter class.

Answer (score 1):

probably

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

not work . you have to add-

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

in your layout. please see this [link](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.in/2011/08/focus-problems-with-list-rows-and.html) for details.

alternatively you can use Button or create own button using native layout.

Answer (score 0):

If it works with an ordinary `Button`, maybe you can just set its background instead of using `ImageButton`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to set the following in your ImageButton -

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Alternatively you can add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the root item of your row layout XML.